# Works in firefox but not IE8

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8

This is working fine in firefox but only closes the first page and then breaks in IE8. Firebug in IE8 says that `x.item(o)` is null. I can't figure out why this works in firefox but not IE. Thanks for any help.

```
pager(x=document.getElementsByName("pg1"));

function pager( x ) {
    var curr = document.getElementById('showing');
    $(curr).fadeOut('fast');
    curr.id = 'hide';
    $(x).fadeIn('slow');
    x.item(0).id ='showing';
}
```

Comment: This is what I get in firebug. "item(...)' is null or not an object"

in firefox when I do alert(x.item(0).id); after the ID is set "showing", the alert msg does display the ID as "showing" but not in IE8. I'm pretty sure that the problem is how i'm setting the ID to "showing". I don't know any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if(x.item(0).id = NULL )

That's an assignment. You wanted `==` for comparison.

(What's NULL in capital letters? An element's `id` property won't be `null`; if it's not set, it'll be an empty string.)

It seems to me you'd be better off using jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

Comment: No that was something I added to test but I guess that was even wrong. The whole statement isn't in there.